# Creating collaborative maps?

Tags: crowdsourcing

I need to suggest a tool to build a map together, ie. let multiple users add POIs and routes on a map.

I know about OSM-based [Umap](http://umap.openstreetmap.fr/en/) but are there other online tools I should know about?

Comment: I think it is worth looking for ideas under the [tag:crowdsourcing] tag.

Comment: Another alternative is https://canvis.app - you can use it to quickly and easily launch a crowdsourcing project from your browser. It is quite flexible and looks great on all screens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google maps engine](https://mapsengine.google.com/map/?) is quite handy for collaborative projects. Map object creation tools are easy to use for non-expert users.

Comment: Since it's for non-techies, I guess Google Maps Engine (Lite) is the right way to do, although I prefered to use an open-source solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [geojson.io](http://geojson.io/)? It let's you collaboratively draw lines, points and also annotate them. This can be shared and embedded easily as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [uebermaps - digital mapping platform](https://uebermaps.com)? It combines features of a CMS (Content Management System) and save locations on maps.

A nice example can be found here: https://uebermaps.com/maps/2732-social-hops-growing-locations- that is used by a community called "urbanfarm" to collect social hops growing locations collaboratively.

[image: uebermaps settings to control collaboration on maps.]

Answer (score 0):

This is a new open source geosocial network platform that allow to create collaborative geospatial contents inside a common map, on the site you can try a working demo:

https://kepler.opengeo.tech

or download the code and run your custom istance in nodejs