# Web Maps for Collecting Information in Questionnaire?

Tags: carto, mapbox, software-recommendations, google-maps-engine, crowdsourcing

I am working with a Non Profit group who are looking for collect information around urban cycling routes.

They would like to know the routes people take to get from point A to point B.

I thought, "well web maps are great for that!"

Are there any out of the box solutions (ie: Google Maps Engine, CartoDB, MapBox, etc.) that would allow for the creation of a web map where people could enter data (draw their cycling route)?

I know that a web map could be made using things like Leaflet, but the group does not have web mapping or web development capabilities.

Ideally, the web map could be embedded into an online survey, and at the end of the survey, the group could access the drawn routes and download them for analysis in a GIS.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You could check question related to 'collaborative mapping' out such as that one http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118815/ or that other one: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80298/

Comment: The [tag:crowdsourcing] tag may turn up some ideas too.

Comment: Hey Ryan! I'm working on a solution right meow that, when finished, should be easy to fork and set up for free by others. Check it out here 
https://github.com/radumas/bikeways4everyone

Answer (score 1):

[Umap](https://umap.openstreetmap.fr/en/) (open source, WTFPL-licensed software) is a web tool that allows you creating and sharing **openstreetmap** maps that can be edited by multiple users.

Once you create a map, you can configure it to be edited by anyone who knows the public url of the created map or only by users who knows a secret url, something that can be very convenient to avoid misuse when the service is public.

Here is an example I'm developing for a collaborative "Cycling routes over quiet streets" map, only editable with a secret link: http://umap.openstreetmap.fr/en/map/mapa-de-calles-tranquilas-de-malaga_36436#13/36.7143/-4.4265

Comment: And the from-now-on-not-so secret link is http://umap.openstreetmap.fr/en/map/anonymous-edit/36436%3ArNuFC_q6KTu6yIm5eNeM775msLo

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the other platforms, but the Google Maps JavaScript API has a drawing library that lets users put lines, points and polygons on the map that you can then store wherever you choose. Check out the [drawing library guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawinglayer) and one of the [examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools).

Another way to get details on routes from your users is to use the [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) (server-side) or the [Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) (in the JS API). There's a neat example of interactively editing directions [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable). Then you can save the generated data wherever you like.

Comment: Thank you Mark, but one of the restrictions is development, regardless of how simple you may think it is.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that part in your question, sorry!